# Unknown schematic symbol (circle with 'c' )

Tags: audio

Came across this symbol while working on a shorted Pioneer Integrated Amp
It's the circle with a C in the center. It looks like only one leg is connected.
[image]

Comment: It's a node reference to another part of the circuit it connects to. Look for a matching node reference. Please link to the full schematic.

Comment: Rather, it's a signal reference drawn by some quack. "I also found some A's"... a circle around an A is the standardized symbol for amperemeter and shouldn't be used for any other purpose.

Comment: I will take a SWAG: I have come across similar items where the "C" in the circle was a checkpoint however this has an arrow which referred you to another point in the circuit with the same symbol. They typically followed the alphabet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have another "C" in your circuit it is a reference to it. the both "Cs" connect to a single point electrically. but for convenience of drawing it is done this way.

Comment: After your reply, I looked over the schematic and found the other C connection, I also found some A's and Some B's that I never noticed. Thanks for your time answering my question.

Comment: no sweat, happy to help.